# How to remove bullet points from the text using regex in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have read solutions on StackOverflow but could not find my answer. Here is the code, I tried the following code to remove various possible bullets:

```
 import re
 x= "1. hi  2) hi   b)  hi  c)  hi  C. hi    I. hi "
 x = re.replace(([0-9|A-Z]+[\.|\)]|)\s+,'',line)
 print(x)
```

I want output as - hi hi hi hi hi

Comment: `" ".join(re.split(r'\s*(?:\d+\.|[A-Za-z]+\))\s*', text)).strip()`

Comment: `[0-9|A-Z]` matches any character in the set, so `0123456789|ABCDEFG...` (key point here is that it also matches `|`). Same goes for the second set.

Comment: Split on `\s*\b(?:\d+|[a-z])[.)]\s*`

Comment: Yeah, splitting and joining is best in suchlike scenarios. `" ".join(re.split(r'\s*(?:\d+|A-Za-z]+)[.)]\s*', text)).strip()` should work.

Comment: Did any solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex, which is a bit simpler than the two above approaches in the comments, but should generally do what you are asking:

```
\w[.)]\s*
```

What this does is get a `character` + `(` or `.` + `optional whitespace` and then you can replace that with an empty string. For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> x= "1. hi  2) hi   b)  hi  c)  hi  C. hi    I. hi "
>>> re.sub(r'\w[.)]\s*', '', x)
'hi  hi   hi  hi  hi    hi '
```

Note a few things here:

1. It's `re.sub` and not `re.replace` (which is what you'd use for a string).
2. There's whitespace inconsistency here -- it's up to you how you want/need to fix that -- in the regex or in python or not at all.
3. If you need to do something with the items, I'd suggest using `re.findall` or `re.search`.
4. Finally, the two comments above are a stronger regex than what I'm using here (especially @Wiktor). You can substitute those into my answer if that's of more help to you, but the above should point you in the right direction.

---

I would probably use an approach similar to the following which uses a basic regex to split on the "list-prefix" and uses python for everything else:

```
>>> [item.strip() for item in re.split('\w[.)]', x) if item]
['hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi']
```

Now you have all the items can you can figure out what you want to do with them.